# Bootstrap 'small' tag not playing nicely with link_to rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue getting the '-' (dash) to be directly in front of the link that uses "@natelie_h" as the anchor text. It breaks it on to the next link for some reason.

```
<div class="span3">
          <blockquote><p>"My favourite part of the service is the information pack that comes with the flies"</p><p><small><%= link_to "@natelie_h", "https://twitter.com/natelie_h", :target => "_blank"  %> </small></p></blockquote>
        </div>
```

Here you can see what I mean: http://www.clockworkflies.com/ (customer quotes, near the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

That is because  and  in have a display:block, and "-" is added before  but "-" is inline, so  is shown on new line

1. Try

   blockquote small a:before {
       content: "— ";
   }

in css, instead of "blockquote small:before"

1. Another option is to set not display:block but display:inline-block for blockquote small and blockquote small a. But IE6 and IE7 does not support this css variable

Comment: That add another "-" but doesn't resovle the issue of the fact that there is essentially a <br> betweent "<small>" and "<%= link_to "@natelie_h","